# How do you extract the parent directory from the absolute pathname of a file stored in a variable using expr in unix?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

For example, I have a path

```
x=/home/john/filename.txt
```

How do I extract only `/home/john` using the `expr` function?

Comment: `expr` evaluates expressions.  It doesn't perform substring operations.

Comment: The man expr contains an entry for substring operations.But I did not understand how to use it.

Comment: Please send me a snippet that would demonstrate the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [dirname](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dirname-invocation.html):

```
$ x=/home/john/filename.txt
$ dirname $x
/home/john
```

EDIT: You seem to be looking for alternatives:

```
$ x=/home/john/filename.txt
$ echo ${x%/*}
/home/john
$ echo ${x:0:10}
/home/john
```

EDIT: It seems that OP was looking for a solution using `expr`.  The accepted solution works assuming a given directory name length.  The following doesn't make that assumption:

```
$ x=/home/john/filename.txt
$ expr $x : '\(.*\)/.*'
/home/john
```

Comment: Oh it was the directory that the OP wanted... deleting mine (facepalm).

Answer (score 0):

This is alternative using `expr` function

```
$ x=/home/john/filename.txt
$ expr $x : '\(.\{10\}\)'
/home/john
```

EDIT: if your path will start with `/home/name` and then will be different length of path use this pattern:

```
$ expr $x : '\([/][a-z]*[/][a-z]*\)'
/home/john
```

Comment: Could you please explain the logig of this snippet?

Comment: `:` means that `expr` will find pattern defined by regular expression and this expression starts from begging and takes ten characters or you could define different patterns for mote info try [REGEXP](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html)